# Mapping a list to the product of the elements excluding the current index without using division

Tags: arrays, haskell

I'm doing some exercies in Haskell, and this is the current one I'm working on https://leetcode.com/problems/product-of-array-except-self/.

> Given an array of n integers where n > 1, nums, return an array output such that output[i] is equal to the product of all the elements of nums except nums[i].
>
> Solve it without division and in O(n).
>
> For example, given [1,2,3,4], return [24,12,8,6].

I was able to do it pretty easily with division:

```
import Data.List (foldl1')

productOfArray :: [Int] -> [Int]
productOfArray xs = f <$> xs
  where p = foldl1' (*)
        f = div (p xs)
```

But I'm not quite sure how to approach it without doing division. The imperative approach is map to the product of all the numbers to the left of the current index times all the numbers to the right of the current index, but in Haskell I'm not quite sure how to conceptualize that.

Comment: For a non-optimized approach, [splitAt](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `tails` and `inits` functions, which return all the elements after and before the Nth.

```
> tails [1,2,3,4]
[[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4], [4]]
```

Note that if you remove the first value, this is exactly the values that you will have to multiply after the missing element.

```
> tail $ tails [1,2,3,4]
[[2,3,4], [3,4], [4]]
```

`inits` will return the values before the missing number

```
> heads [1,2,3,4]
[[], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]]
```

Finally, use the product function and a zipwith to do the final multiplication.

```
zipWith (*) (map product $ inits [1,2,3,4]) (map product $ tail $ tails [1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: This solution looks quadratic, but the question asks for O(n).  You could refactor using `map product . inits = scanl (*) 1` and `map product . tails = scanr (*) 1`